# Aliasing rules and making Rust function "generic over aliasing"

Tags: rust, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

I have a routine which takes in an immutable slice of points and performs some transformation, writing to a mutable slice of points. (As a simple example, let's say we translate all the points by some constant.) Suppose also that the implementation cannot be reduced to a point-by-point processing. (In my case, I have vectorized the algorithm after confirming that the compiler can't do it automatically.)

While minimizing duplicate code, I want the routine to work with both 1. transforming one array to a different array, and 2. transforming a single, mutable array in-place.

Suppose the existing implementation has the form

```rust
fn transform(in_: &[Point], out: &mut [Point], translate: Point) {
   // ...
}
```

This solves case (1), but because we can't borrow the same array mutably and immutably at the same time, this will not work for case (2). Indeed, trying to use unsafe, and get simultaneous mutable and immutable references, is instant undefined behavior.

How can we get around this problem? Can we bypass the rules by doing something like

```rust
unsafe fn transform_impl(in_: &[UnsafeCell<Point>], out: &[UnsafeCell<Point>], translate: Point) {
  // ... promise we won't modify in_ here, nor have overlapping lifetimes
  // between values read from in_ and written to out ...
}

fn transform_in_place(inout: &mut [Point], translate: Point) {
  unsafe {
    let a: &[UnsafeCell<Point>] = std::mem::transmute(inout);
    transform_impl(a, a, translate);
  }
}

fn transform(in_: &[Point], out: &mut [FPoint], translate: Point) {
  unsafe {
    transform_impl(std::mem::transmute(in_), std::mem::transmute(out), translate);
  }
}
```

using interior mutability, and promise that we won't change values in `out` from "underneath" the values in `in_`? Or is casting an immutable slice to an UnsafeCell slice, like before, instant undefined behavior?

(In C, we can just use pointers, since non-`restrict` pointers of the same type may alias.)

I would prefer to have a single function to handle both cases, if only to minimize the amount of duplicate generated code. If this is ultimately impractical, what would be an elegant way to make this work without implementing the algorithm in source twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transmuting `&mut T` to `&UnsafeCell<T>` (and therefore `&mut [Point]` to `&[UnsafeCell<Point>]` is definitely fine. [This is documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html#memory-layout). You do have to be careful to not hold a mutable and shared reference at the same time, though, which means restricting the access to either `&` from `in_` or `&mut` from `out`, but not both at the same time for the same index. It may even be possible to do it safely, using [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), with [`Cell::from_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.from_mut) and [`Cell::as_slice_of_cells()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.as_slice_of_cells) (depending on how you need to access the `Point`s).

The problem is the other cast, `&T` to `&UnsafeCell<T>`. If the reference is then written into, this is undoubtedly UB. The question is what happens when we only create a reference and not write into it.

Stacked Borrows marks this UB. Tree Borrows (another possible aliasing model) accepts this. It is my understanding that people want this to be allowed, but it is unclear how to allow this with Stacked Borrows.

Given the aliasing model is not decided yet, I'd recommend to avoid this pattern. It is possible to do what you want if you take raw points and not references; this does mean more unsafe code, though.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer; I suspected this was a bit of an unresolved/language lawyer question. In practice, would rustc/LLVM exploit the undefined behavior you diagnosed? Regarding the final option, is it possible to alias a *mut T with a *const T? If so, then I'd be fine creating some sort of safe-ish macro system with manual bounds checks to do this.

Comment: @OvinusReal *In practice, would rustc/LLVM exploit the undefined behavior you diagnosed?* - this is a slippery-slope question because even if the answer were "no" today, that might change with a new release of rustc or LLVM.

Comment: @OvinusReal rustc won't create a LLVM UB for that code (if it would, Tree Borrows could not allow it). But as user4815162342 said, it does not matter, since you program for the Rust Abstract Machine and not LLVM's. Aliasing pointers is fine, as long as they are created from the same mutable reference. As always, check your code with Miri.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using traits to handle this case.

You can create a trait that defines "point I/O", with methods to get immutable and mutable slices.  Then you can implement it for `&mut [Point]` (for the in-place case) and `(&[Point], &mut [Point])` for the non-overlapping case.

The trait need not be public, as you can provide different public functions to handle each case, but that delegate to a common implementation function.

This requires that the implementation can be written in a way that doesn't require reads that overlap with writes.

```
use std::slice::SliceIndex;

struct Point;

trait PointIO {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;

    fn get<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&self, range: I) -> &I::Output;
    fn get_mut<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&mut self, range: I) -> &mut I::Output;
}

impl PointIO for &mut [Point] {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        <[Point]>::len(self)
    }

    fn get<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&self, range: I) -> &I::Output {
        &self[range]
    }

    fn get_mut<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&mut self, range: I) -> &mut I::Output {
        &mut self[range]
    }
}

impl PointIO for (&[Point], &mut [Point]) {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        std::cmp::min(self.0.len(), self.1.len())
    }

    fn get<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&self, range: I) -> &I::Output {
        &self.0[range]
    }

    fn get_mut<I: SliceIndex<[Point]>>(&mut self, range: I) -> &mut I::Output {
        &mut self.1[range]
    }
}

fn transform_impl(points: impl PointIO, translate: Point) {
    todo!()
}

fn transform(in_: &[Point], out: &mut [Point], translate: Point) {
    transform_impl((in_, out), translate);
}

fn transform_overlapping(inout: &mut [Point], translate: Point) {
    transform_impl(inout, translate);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I certainly miss something, but I don't understand how `transform_impl()` can be implemented. Invoking `points.get()` **and** `points.get_mut()` causes necessarily a mutable borrow on `points`. Then, in the end, it seems to me that we still have the original problem of the question requiring `UnsafeCell` and `transmute()` as a workaround.

Comment: @prog-fh We don't have all of the details of the implementation, so it's hard to say 100% for sure, but it could work in the case that reads and writes can alternate, for example. That is, `get()` can be used to copy a small amount of data into a local buffer, a transformation applied, then `get_mut()` can be used to write the data where it needs to go.

Comment: @prog-fh Also, while this particular solution may not exactly work for OP, it does answer the question posed in the _title_, so it could provide an idea for those arriving here from Google. It is a workable solution for writing a single implementation that is "generic over aliasing." Whether it would work depends entirely on the details of the algorithm being implemented.

Comment: Yes, I was certainly over-focusing on a vectorised version of an algorithm which translates all the points by some constant. But if another use case does not imply iterating over the provided slices (do we still need them?) that makes sense. Maybe should we adapt this solution in order to provide aliased `&` and `&mut` in general, not necessarily slices.

Comment: @prog-fh Yeah, a more general solution would certainly be useful to others. I kept it focused on access to slices per OP's question, but the general pattern of "trait providing distinct read and write methods, implemented on `&mut T` and `(&T, &mut T)`" is definitely widely applicable, I would think.

Comment: @prog-fh Thinking about this more, I think the I/O trait bound could simply be `AsRef<T> + AsMut<T>`, though it would require newtypes to implement.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, instead of relying on transmute, I suggest defining `transform_inplace()` with all the details and provide simple adapters for cases in which the transform does not need to occur in place.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

fn transform_inplace(
    inout: &mut [Point],
    translate: Point,
) {
    for p in inout.iter_mut() {
        p.x += translate.x;
        p.y += translate.y;
    }
}

fn transform(
    input: &[Point],
    output: &mut [Point],
    translate: Point,
) {
    output.clone_from_slice(input);
    transform_inplace(output, translate);
}

fn transformed(
    input: &[Point],
    translate: Point,
) -> Vec<Point> {
    let mut output = input.to_owned();
    transform_inplace(&mut output, translate);
    output
}

fn main() {
    {
        let mut points = [
            Point { x: 1.1, y: 2.2 },
            Point { x: 3.3, y: 4.4 },
            Point { x: 5.5, y: 6.6 },
        ];
        transform_inplace(&mut points, Point { x: 10.0, y: 20.0 });
        println!("transform_inplace(): {:?}", points);
    }
    {
        let input = [
            Point { x: 1.1, y: 2.2 },
            Point { x: 3.3, y: 4.4 },
            Point { x: 5.5, y: 6.6 },
        ];
        let mut output = [Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }; 3];
        transform(&input, &mut output, Point { x: 10.0, y: 20.0 });
        println!("transform(): {:?}", output);
    }
    {
        let input = [
            Point { x: 1.1, y: 2.2 },
            Point { x: 3.3, y: 4.4 },
            Point { x: 5.5, y: 6.6 },
        ];
        let output = transformed(&input, Point { x: 10.0, y: 20.0 });
        println!("transformed(): {:?}", output);
    }
}
/*
transform_inplace(): [Point { x: 11.1, y: 22.2 }, Point { x: 13.3, y: 24.4 }, Point { x: 15.5, y: 26.6 }]
transform(): [Point { x: 11.1, y: 22.2 }, Point { x: 13.3, y: 24.4 }, Point { x: 15.5, y: 26.6 }]
transformed(): [Point { x: 11.1, y: 22.2 }, Point { x: 13.3, y: 24.4 }, Point { x: 15.5, y: 26.6 }]
*/
```